# Set a program or bash as default program for *.rdp files

Tags: executable, xfreerdp

I have a xfreerdp connection file like:

```
xfreerdp /v:10.1.60.151 -sec-nla /cert-ignore
```

The file name is `test.rdp` and I can run it with the command `bash test.rdp`

But I need to run this file from GUI with double click or auto start when its downloaded from chrome.

I don't mind changing the filename extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you have binfmt_misc mounted, run

```
echo :rdp:E::rdp::/usr/bin/xfreerdp:: > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

You can see a full write-up on the binfmt_misc file extension here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt

It requires kernel support (every distro I know of ships it) as well as mounting the filesystem in /proc.